# Change select option after reload form

Tags: jquery

```js
function addVideoField () {
        jQuery('#ug_content').change(function()
        {
            url = jQuery("#ug_content option:selected").text();
            jQuery.get( stringUrl + url + "#doc", function( message ) {
                var frombla = jQuery(message).find("#ugc-media-form-doc").html();
                jQuery( "#ugc-media-form-doc" ).html( frombla );
                addVideoField();
            });
        });
    }
    addVideoField();
```

After change select option, form is reloaded as I want, but, select option is changing to first option in list.
Tried to write this,

```js
jQuery("#ug_content").val(url);
```

but not worked.

Comment: Why are you replacing the `select` element in the first place?

Comment: Are the value and the text in the option the same? Because if they are not, it will never work: first you save the text, then try the value. It's not consistent